# Hello, I want put Box with and height on the picture _ what is the best solution in Html CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

I want put Box with and height on the picture _ what is the best solution in Html CSS ?

but i dont want use position: absolute ,  top: 50px  for example

i used position: absolute and used position: relative on the img tag ...
i think its not easy way    ????

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        z-index: 0;
      }
      .boxWrapper {
        padding: 10px;
      }
      .box {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        margin-top: -125px;
        margin-left: 75px;
        background-color: black;
        z-index: 1;
      }
```

```html
   <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="boxWrapper">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?random=1" alt="" />
        <div class="box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="boxWrapper">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?random=2" alt="" />
        <div class="box"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```